# How to put all parts of an adjacent same elements into a single stuff in the output, grouping by IDs with xslt, where parts are identified from IDs?

Tags: xslt

INPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<he>
 <p>...some text 111.</p>
 <figure id="c01-fig-001">
  <section id="c01-sec-1418">
   <title type="main">A Journey</title>
   <section id="c01-sec-1218">
    <p>My para.</p>
   </section>
  </section>
  <caption>My Fig 1.</caption>
 </figure>
 <p>...some text 222.</p>
 <figure id="c01-fig-002" role="noart">
  <section id="c01-sec-1518">
   <title type="main">An Abstract 2</title>
    <section id="c01-sec-3218">
     <p>My para1 2.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="c01-sec-5218">
     <p>My para2 2.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <caption>My Fig 2.</caption>
 </figure>
 <figure id="c01-fig-002a" role="noart">
  <section id="c01-sec-1418">
   <section id="c01-sec-1318">
    <p>My para3 2a.</p>
   </section>
   <section id="c01-sec-1218">
    <p>My para4 2a.</p>
   </section>
  </section>
 </figure>
 <figure id="c01-fig-002b" role="noart">
   <section id="c01-sec-1418">
    <title type="main">An Abstract 2b</title>
    <section id="c01-sec-1318">
      <p>My para5 2b.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
 </figure>
 <figure id="c01-fig-002c" role="noart">
  <section id="c01-sec-1208">
   <title type="main">An Abstract 2c</title>
   <section id="c01-sec-1158">
    <title>Last para of last part 2c</title>
    <p>My para6 2c.</p>
   </section>
  </section>
 </figure>
 <p>...some text 333.</p>
 <figure id="c01-fig-003" role="noart">
  <section id="c01-sec-1818">
   <title type="main">Pre Production 3</title>
    <section id="c01-sec-3518">
     <p>My para1 3.</p>
    </section>
   <section id="c01-sec-1218">
    <p>My para2 3.</p>
   </section>
  </section>
  <caption>My Fig 3.</caption>
 </figure>
  <p>...some text 333.</p>
  <figure id="c01-fig-003a" role="noart">
    <section id="c01-sec-1718">
     <title type="main">Pre Production 3a</title>
    <section id="c01-sec-3158">
      <p>My para3 3a.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="c01-sec-1628">
     <p>My para4 3a.</p>
    </section>
   </section>
  </figure>
  <p>...some text 444.</p>
  <figure id="c01-fig-004">
    <section id="c01-sec-1128">
      <title type="main">Some Text 4</title>
      <section id="c01-sec-3118">
        <p>My para1 4.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="c01-sec-1328">
       <p>My para2 4.</p>
      </section>
    </section>
    <caption>My Fig 4.</caption>
 </figure>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section/p">
  <h3><xsl:apply-templates/></h3>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="figure/section/title">
  <h1><xsl:apply-templates/></h1>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section/section/title">
  <p><i><xsl:apply-templates/></i></p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="caption">
  <caption><xsl:apply-templates/></caption>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="figure">
 <xsl:if test="number(substring-after(@id, '-fig-'))">
  <aside type="figure">
 <div id="{substring-after(@id, '-fig-')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="contains(following-sibling::figure[1]/@id, @id)">
       <PART><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::figure" mode="noart"/></PART>
    </xsl:if>
 </div>
  </aside>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="figure" mode="noart">
  <xsl:if test="contains(preceding-sibling::figure[1]/@id, substring(@id, 1, string-length(@id) - 1))">
    <xsl:if test="matches(@id, substring(preceding-sibling::figure[1]/@id, 1, string-length(preceding-sibling::figure[1]/@id) - 1))">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
<p>...some text 111.</p>
<aside type="figure">
   <div id="001">
      <h1>A Journey</h1>
     <h3>My para.</h3>
   <caption>My Fig 1.</caption>
  </div>
</aside>
<p>...some text 222.</p>
<aside type="figure">
 <div id="002">
  <h1>An Abstract 2</h1>
     <h3>My para1 2.</h3>
     <h3>My para2 2.</h3>
  <caption>My Fig 2.</caption>
  <PART>
        <h3>My para3 2a.</h3>
        <h3>My para4 2a.</h3>

     <h1>An Abstract 2b</h1>
        <h3>My para5 2b.</h3>

     <h1>An Abstract 2c</h1>
        <p>
        <i>Last para of last part 2c</i>
     </p>
        <h3>My para6 2c.</h3>

     <h1>Pre Production 3a</h1>  -------SHOULD NOT BE HERE(as part of fig-3)
        <h3>My para3 3a.</h3>    -------SHOULD NOT BE HERE(as part of fig-3)
        <h3>My para4 3a.</h3>    -------SHOULD NOT BE HERE(as part of fig-3)
  </PART>
 </div>
</aside>

<p>...some text 333.</p>
<aside type="figure">
 <div id="003">
  <h1>Pre Production 3</h1>
     <h3>My para1 3.</h3>
     <h3>My para2 3.</h3>
  <caption>My Fig 3.</caption>
  <PART>
     <h1>Pre Production 3a</h1>
        <h3>My para3 3a.</h3>
        <h3>My para4 3a.</h3>
  </PART>
 </div>
</aside>
<p>...some text 333.</p>
<p>...some text 444.</p>
<aside type="figure">
 <div id="004">
  <h1>Some Text 4</h1>
     <h3>My para1 4.</h3>
     <h3>My para2 4.</h3>
  <caption>My Fig 4.</caption>
 </div>
</aside>
```

NOTE: the number part of ID after [-fig-] to be matched i.e. [001, 002, 003, ...].

for e.g., figure with id like `c01-fig-002` should be matched with `c01-fig-002a | c01-fig-002b ...` where the last character `a|b|c...` indicates that these are the parts of the same bundle and to be kept in a single bundle in output.

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: Your textual description (stuffed into the subject line) seems to suggest you want to group some elements by a part of the `id` attribute value. Can you edit your question and provide a verbal description in the question as to which parts of the `id` have to matched/compared to group the elements?

Comment: @Martin Honnen >> the number part of 'id' after [-fig-] to be matched i.e. [001, 002, 003, ...] for grouping in output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer:

1. add a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="./@id"/>
```

2. the line **<PART><xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::figure" mode="noart"/></PART>** should be like

```
<PART>
    <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::figure[matches(@id,$ID)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="noart"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</PART>
```

3. the template **<xsl:template match="figure" mode="noart">** should read as

```
<xsl:template match="figure" mode="noart">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```